# Carregar mais não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma section onde recebe alguns posts e tem um botão de carregar mais. Na minha section o primeiro post exibe corretamente, mas quando eu clico no botão de carregar mais, não executa o segundo post q era para aparecer.

> Minha section | complemento/section-um.php   = Local que fica minha section
>
> Meu botão | complemento/section.botao.php = Local que fica meu botão
>
> Meu javascript | complemento/carregar_mais_js.js = Local que fica meu botão

```
//Carrega um conteúdo inicial ao carregar a página
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
        url: 'complemento/section-um.php',
        data: {PG:1},
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(response){

            $('#Section_index_NV').html(response);
        }
   }); 
});

//Carrega um conteúdo ao clicar no botão
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CarregarNVs').click(function(){

        let proxima_pagina = $(this).attr('data-ref');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'complemento/section-um.php',
            data: {PG:proxima_pagina},
            type: 'GET',

            success: function(response){

                console.log(response);
                $('#Section_index_NV').append(response);
            },

            complete: function(){

                $('#CarregarNVs').attr('data-ref', parseInt(proxima_pagina) + 1);
            }
       }); 
    });
});
```

Página do meu botão:

```
<div class="Carregar_mais">
        <center>
            <button id="CarregarNVs" title="Carregar mais" class="CarregarNVs" data-ref="2">Carregar mais</button>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: O que acontece, tem algum erro no console? Cai no callback de erro do ajax, nao renderiza na tela..?

Comment: o console não retorna nenhum erro, mas agora q eu dei uma olhada, quando eu clico no botão ele executa apenas a parte do titulo do minha section (Ou seja ele duplica o inicio da section, mas n aparece outro post).

Comment: voce esta enviado um `data` em um `GET`, nao seria `POST`?

Comment: Sim era isso msm, estava como GET mudei para o POST e funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está enviando a propriedade `data` no Ajax do jQuery com um método `GET`. Como o *end-point* é um post, altere para `type: 'POST'`.